# Using HornetQ InVM between multiple apps

Tags: java, jms, hornetq

Since HornetQ has the concept of **InVM** Acceptors and Connectors, is it possible to configure HornetQ **Embedded** in a way that two different Apps in the same Tomcat instance could send messages to each other?

I saw that HornetQ keeps some informations about addresses and queues in MBeans, so I thought that they could share these infos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The InVM Acceptor and Connector concept is orthogonal to the MBeans and addresses. So I'm not really sure what you are asking about them.

You can just have InVM acceptors and connectors as long as you can properly embed HornetQ at your VM.

Comment: I was wondering if two different Apps, A and B, running on the same Tomcat instance (thus same VM), and using HornetQ embedded, could exchange messages with each other.
I would like to avoid having to deploy a centralized HornetQ server.

Comment: Sure.. that shouldn't be a problem. We do that all the time on JBoss.
One Application will send a message to a destination A, the other application will listen on a consumer on the same destination.

You need to make sure the setup is working properly though. That works fine on JBoss without any issues.

Comment: Hum, I see. Could you explain me what is you setup like?

Comment: Just FYI, here is how I setup my apps:
In my tests I've deployed two similar apps in Tomcat. Both started an Embedded HornetQ server. They had Queues bound to the same Address, and they sent messages to this same address. But the consumers just received messages from their own app.

I tried to start a HornetQ server in only one of the apps, but then the other one wouldn't locate the server.

Comment: That's wrong: You need to do a proper integration of HornetQ being started by Tomcat on the main classLoader. Otherwise each application (with its own classLoader) won't be able to select the other classLoader's application

Comment: I see, it must be in a common classloader. Thanks very much Clebert, I'll do some testing now.

Valeu hehe!